# Windows 7, Dell laptop Dell external monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

When I close the lid of my laptop the external screen rotates 90 degrees so have to leave the laptop open to work on.  I've tried to correct in display setting and both the laptop and the monitor are in landscape, which is what I want.  How do I stop the external monitor going to portrait when I close the lid.